# How to initialize a static variable only when at least one instance has been created

Tags: java, import, static, initialization

Suppose I have a class with two static final variables, one of which is imported by another class. E.g.,

```
// File 1
import static com.company.Dependency.y;

class Import {
    // Some code...
}
```

and

```
// File 2
class Dependency {
    public static final Something y = new Something();
    private static final Otherthing x = new Otherthing();

    // Some code...
}
```

In two static fields, `x` is only relevant to instances of class Dependency, say the number of Dependency objects, and is expensive to initialize. I don't want to initialize `x` unless at least one instance of class Dependency is instantiated. But in this case the `import static` statement will accidentally trigger initialization of `x`. What's the best practice to handle such situation?

Here's my current implementation. Unfortunately it doesn't preserve the final attribute for `x`:

```
class Dependency {
    public static final Something y = new Something();
    private static Otherthing x = null;

    public Dependency() {
        if (Dependency.x == null) {
            x = new Otherthing();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Make the field `private`, ignore that it is not `final`, write a `static` getter. Keep in mind that your current implementation is not thread-safe.

Comment: Because constructors can be called from multiple threads, you also might want to consider synchronizing the code that check for and assigns `x`.

Answer (score 1):

I would consider a factory method for something like this

```
public class Dependency {
    private static Dependency xHolder;

    public static synchronized Dependency get() {
        if( xHolder == null ) xHolder = new Dependency();
        return xHolder;
    }
```

But I'd also consider implementing with a second inner class which will remove the need for explicit synchronization and can also be made `final`:

```
public class Dependency {
    private static class Holder {
       static final Dependency x = new Dependency();
    }

    public static Dependency get() {
        return Holder.x;
    }
```

Comment: This still leaves him with a non-final member in his class, which he could achieve with his current approach.

Comment: Oh, well I guess the second way could be made `final` too.  I'll update.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a helper class.

Although it may not be preferable syntax-wise, you'll be able to keep your members `static final`.

```
class Demo {
    private static final Something something = new Something();

    public Demo() {
        Helper.x.doSomething();
    }

    private static final class Helper {
        private static final Otherthing x = new OtherThing();
    }
}

class Otherthing {
    public void doSomething() { }
}

class Something { }
```

By adding print statements to the top of each type's constructor, running this as:

```
Class c = Demo.class; // loads the class
Demo demo = new Demo();
```

Results in:

```
Something constructor was called!
Demo constructor was called!
Otherthing constructor was called!
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to keep x in a static Dependency object that only gets created when it needs to be. You can then use a static method to return x from your static dependency object. The constructor is private to prevent Dependency objects from be created outside the Dependency class.

```
public class Dependency {
    public static final Something y = new Something();
    private static Dependency xHolder;

    /*
     * Call this to get x, creating it if necessary.
     */
    public static Otherthing getX() {
        if(xHolder == null) {
            xHolder = new Dependency();
        }
        return xHolder.x;
    }

    private final Otherthing x = new Otherthing();
    private Dependency(){

    }

}
```

Comment: His variable can't be `final` using this approach. He would like to declare the variable final. He already had a non-final approach.